# NavController add fragment instead replace without using Dialog

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I want to create a youtube like animation using MotionLayout. When I used FragmentManager i added fragment, and then when it minimized i could handle events in previous fragment because it was visible.

But as I understood NavController replace fragments instead of add it.

How can i achieve this animation using NavController

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two states to be separate destinations you can handle it via a shared element transition which Navigation Component supports. [This blog post](https://medium.com/@serbelga/shared-elements-in-android-navigation-architecture-component-bc5e7922ecdf) has a helpful tutorial on how to do that.